# Using header files from the static library in project

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm developing application in OSX 10.9 and Xcode 5.0.2
I'm using making workspace. It separates on two parts. Static library and bundle application.
Bundle application should link static library and includes headers for the static library which I added to the Public header group in the Build Phase of the Target. Also I've prescribed $(PRODUCT_BUILD_DIR)/usr/local/include in the header search path of the bundle app. 
But problem - bundle app target doesn't see header files of static library target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer. Predefined path was set as user header search path but in code I used #import "" instead of #import <>. So right answer - use proper import syntax.